# How to add Fullscreen icon in Qt in the title bar of an OSX app?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, fullscreen, qtquick2

I recently started developing an app in C++ & Qt 5.1 and I would like to have the double-arrowed icon on the title bar of my window like other Mac apps.
I created a QtQuick 2 Application project and the default code doesn't make this button appear.
I noticed that QtQuick 2 UI default project shows this button.
I really don't understand why. Is there someone who can help me ?

Thanks a lot for your answers,

jnconte.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with qtquick, but if it's the same project file as Qt, you would create the icon (icns file) and add it to the project file like this: -

```
ICON = images/icon.icns
```

The icon.icns file, in this case, is in a folder called images, relative to the project file.